# Strange behaviour with $_SESSION on 2 remote server

Tags: php, session

This is my situation
I have 2 server, `server_1` hosts a page, `server_2` a webapp. You can log into the `server_2`'s webapp by the page of `server_1`, making a post call passing the username and encrypted password, and a parameter which determinate if you are coming from `server_1` page or directly from the login form of the webapp on `server_2`.
When you log in I use a lot of `$_SESSION` variable to store infos about current logged user and a lot of ajax call directly to a php file (`req.php`). Now, if I log in from the webapp form on `server_2` I haven't problem, but if I login from the `server_1` when it's time to make and ajax call, I can't get the session value correctly (only from the php of ajax code, the rest of the app works good).
There is another strange behaviour when you log from the `server_1`. Example:

`User_1` logs in from the `server_1`, after that you use the webapp, you close the tab and return to the `server_1` page, logout, login with `user_2`, click your dynamic link to log in on the `server_2` and the webapp create the same session id (I see the file ses_randomid on the php directory) of the previous one! So you are stole another user's session...

I use in the index.php and the req.php (the file used for handling ajax call):

```
session_name("kreker");
session_start();
```

When I debug the call from the webapp to req.php, the `$_SESSION` variable isn't not set, either if i call `session_start()`, and this only happens if you log from the `server_1`. If you login from the webapp directly, the variable is set!

Tried to make an ajax call on close browser event for force destroying the session, works but I think it's not the correct solution.
I also tried with `session_regenerate_id()`, now results;

So the problem is: I login via `POST` request from another server, store the session value, close browser without logout, login via `POST` with another credential, and you are logged like the previous user!  It's possible that this happens because the session of the `server_1` is always the same? (per session I mean you don't close the browser)

Sorry, It's very hard to explain, hope you understand

Comment: Before logging the user in, you must do a session_destroy(), so that it removes his all previously existing sessions. Have you done that?

Comment: Yes, but I still have the problem when I call the req.php file because in this part the session is already started and I need it in this file, but if I call session_start() the session do not appears.

Comment: I cannot understand the part: "because in this part the session is already started". Can you elaborate why exactly you can't call session_destroy() before the user logs in?

Comment: Posting the code-snippet for the concerned component might help.

Comment: I can call it, but it's not working. When you log in a file for the session is created, when you close the browser the file still exist on the server, when you change the username from server_1 and login, it's use the same id of the session of the other user. It did not create a new id, I don't understand why. The only way to resolve this is to force deleting the session file when you close the browser via ajax call, but I don't know if is the correct way

Comment: >>force deleting the session file when you close the browser via ajax call, but I don't know if is the correct way... Thats not the correct way at all - your authentication logic should never depend on the events at client side, since they are not under your control. Rather, try and see if you can come up with an authentication logic BEFORE logging the user in.

Comment: When the user puts his username/pass, you must be creating some session variables on server side, right? Why not delete the old session file at that time?